# path for own .xdy file

Tags: paths, xindy

when I a put a .xdy in the current folder, texxindy find it well. However, if a put it in `<localtexmf>/xindy`, texindy don't find it.

Is it possible to have a personnal styles in a `<localtexmf>` ?

Comment: no, imho xindy doesn't use kpathsea (yet). Adaptions must go in the main tree (there are some open problems in xindy).

Comment: ok. fortunatly, symbolic links works...

Comment: I see, many open problems. The dev seems not to be longer active... http://sourceforge.net/p/xindy/feature-requests/